# pgfplots: How to place the legend box in the middle of an axis

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to have something like

```
legend pos= west, %insted of north west, south east...
```

because I don't wanna place it in the corner but vertically in the middle.

How could I do this?

Comment: Can you please complete your code to a compilable example?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`legend pos=south west` is equivalent to

```
legend style={at={(0.03,0.03)},anchor=south west}
```

So by analogy we can make a version anchored west by using

```
legend style={at={(0.03,0.5)},anchor=west}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[legend style={at={(0.03,0.5)},anchor=west}]
    \addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] coordinates {
    (0,2) (2,3) (3,1)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Case 1}
    \addplot[smooth,color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
    (0,0) (1,1) (2,1) (3,2)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Case 2}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Pgfplots manual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) pag. 179. Use

```
legend style={at={(0.97,0.5)},anchor=east}
```

to have it inside the axes box, vertically centered on the right or (as suggest Andrew Swann in his answer)

```
legend style={at={(0.03,0.5)},anchor=west}
```

to have it on the left.

Comment: Updated link for the pgfplots manual.  http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf